# Save JMeter summary table data without plugin?

Tags: testing, csv, jmeter

Is there any way whatsoever that I can save the summary table data from my JMeter tests each time they are run without using the command line or a plugin of any sorts? You can output the default values in a csv which I am already doing so surely there must be a way to do the same with the average, min, max and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure filename, where are you going to save result right here - in Summary Report. Find field: Write result to file/Read from file.

In case you are going to run JMeter in non-gui mode, you could configure format in which the testing results will be saved. You can chose xml or csv. Use  [jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format](http://blazemeter.com/blog/useful-jmeter-properties-save-results-save-world) config in jmeter.properties.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I am looking to put values that aren't the default values such as min, max, value from the summary report into a csv file? Currently only the default values are present like label, sample time and status.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Add a Simple Data Writer (Test Plan > Add > Listeners > Simple Data Writer) and then give it the path that you want to save to. You can configure the result data that you want to keep. You can then load this file back into any of the reports, results trees, etc. and see the full test results again.

Comment: But the simple data writer doesn't write average , min, max, Std dev...those value presented in a summary report.

Comment: If I recall, those are calculations made from the data present in the output. I believe we add these back in with a perl script

Comment: you mean we can find min, max, std dev in output csv of the summary report?  But I cannot find it in csv. Each row in csv will look like:
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency
1404202870989,7,/localhost,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,738,1,1,7